# Обход пробела в строке

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++, stl, ввод

Вот код сбственно

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char string[100];
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    cin >> string;
    int i = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    cout << "Вне строки: " << string << endl;
    cout << "То что в скобке (): ";
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (string[i] == '(') {
            flag = true;
            i++;
        }
        if (string[i] == ')') {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (flag)
            cout << string[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Код делает такую штуку, ввожу строку, к примеру sadasdsa(asdasd) то в

```
cout << "Вне строки: " << string << endl;
```

будет sadasdsa, а в

```
cout << "То что в скобке (): ";
```

выведет (asdasd)

но если ввести строку sadasdsa (asdasd) с пробелом то есть то строку в скобках не увидет, помогите фиксануть, пробовал через continue но не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `>>` для `istream` и `string` читает **одно слово**.

Воспользуйтесь, например, [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).